# Filtering and code completion do not work when '#' character is used

Tags: vscode-extensions, code-completion, language-server-protocol

I've reproduced the problem in [lsp-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/lsp-sample/server/src/server.ts) (description of my original post moved below).

The code completion does not work with `#` character. How to make it work?

Added `CompletionItem` for `#1000`:

```
connection.onCompletion(
    (_textDocumentPosition: TextDocumentPositionParams): CompletionItem[] => {
        return [
            {
                label: 'TypeScript',
                kind: CompletionItemKind.Text,
                data: 1,
            },
            {
                label: 'JavaScript',
                kind: CompletionItemKind.Text,
                data: 2,
            },
            {
                label: '#1000',
                kind: CompletionItemKind.Text,
                data: 3,
            },
        ];
    }
);
```

Now typing `#` or `#1` does not show/filter the completion list. Choosing `#1000` from the list does not completes properly, i.e. makes `##1000`.

For filtering tried adding `filterText: '#[0-9]+',` or `filterText: '#',` to no avail.

For completion tried below but it does not work when there is something before `#1` in the same line:

```
textEdit: InsertReplaceEdit.create(
                    '#1000',
                    Range.create(
                        Position.create(_textDocumentPosition.position.line, 0),
                        _textDocumentPosition.position
                    ),
                    Range.create(
                        Position.create(_textDocumentPosition.position.line, 0),
                        _textDocumentPosition.position
                    )
                ),
```

=================(My previous post)=======================

I have the following code completion list defined:

```
[
    {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 6,
        "result": [
            {
                "label": "G253",
                "kind": 15,
                "insertTextFormat": 2,
                "data": 106
            },
            {
                "label": "G254",
                "kind": 15,
                "insertTextFormat": 2,
                "data": 107
            },
            {
                "label": "G255",
                "kind": 15,
                "insertTextFormat": 2,
                "data": 108
            },
            {
                "label": "#3000",
                "kind": 15,
                "insertTextFormat": 2,
                "data": 215
            },
            {
                "label": "#3001",
                "kind": 15,
                "insertTextFormat": 2,
                "data": 216
            },
            {
                "label": "#3002",
                "kind": 15,
                "insertTextFormat": 2,
                "data": 217
            },
            {
                "label": "#3003",
                "kind": 15,
                "insertTextFormat": 2,
                "data": 218
            },
            {
                "label": "#3004",
                "kind": 15,
                "insertTextFormat": 2,
                "data": 219
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

When typing `#` and triggering code completion, further typing `#3` does not make the list filtered. Then selecting for example `#3002` from the list inserts double hash: `##3002`.
What am I missing here?

However there is no problem if I use other character than `#`, for example `G`. Then everything works with no problem - proper completion list filtering and inserting, for example `G254`.